# camera orthographic/perspective

Tags: rendering, camera, layers

How to make orthographic view to be constant (as in 2.78)? "num 1" turns the view into front orthographic position but after rotating with MMB the view is perspective again.

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question per post. You are welcome to ask multiple questions, but as separate posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The behavior of the viewport, reverting to a perspective view from any of the set orthogonal views, is a User Preference, and can be set here:

[image]

2. The 2.7x system of layers and render layers has been entirely replaced with [Collections](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/collections/introduction.html) and [View Layers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/layers/layers.html). which are much more flexible, and in the end, easier to use. Beyond the manual,  there are tutorials out there.. I hope this helps by giving you productive search terms.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Mx0tr You're welcome. The comments were right about the question though..because much of  the point of SE sites is to form a nice clean archive for future users. So it's not quite the same as an ordinary discussion forum.